# C# regex to match string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently having difficulty matching strings with my regex. The objective is to match:

- One or two letters
- One, two or three numbers
- Zero or one asterisk

Such as U21, F305 and H12*. The regex that I'm using is:

```
\D{1,2}\d{1,3}\*?
```

However, it's been matching strings like:

- 3.0L
- 6HBW20
- 3/8"
- Y1015

I'm not too bright with regex, but this is holding me from completing my project. Can anyone help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you matching these strings inside of a larger block of text, or is it the whole string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\D` matches any non-digit, which is a much larger set than just letters (basically *everything else*, including periods, slashes, etc). Try using `[a-zA-Z]{1,2}` to match 1 or 2 letters.

```
[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{1,3}\*?
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `/^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{1,3}\*?$/`

The anchors ^ and $ are useful to make sure that you match exactly the pattern you intend. Read up on them :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to *anchor* your match. `^` anchors the match to start of line; `$` drops anchor at end of line.

Try this regular expression

```
@"^[\p{L}]{1,2}\d{1,3}[*]?$"
```